# How to request and get the response in soap web services c#

Tags: c#, webrequest

I have the .asmx url that i need to get the order details by order number.

My problem is that when i execute the code it bring back the html design of 'http://domain.co.za/services/portal.asmx?op=GetOrderDefinition' without populating the response.
here is my code

```
 var client = new RestClient("http://domain.co.za/services/portal.asmx?op=GetOrderDefinition");
        var requests = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

        client.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
        client.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        requests.AddHeader("Host", "test.lensportal.co.za");
        requests.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        requests.AddHeader("SOAPAction", "http://www.domain.co.za/GetOrderDefinition");

        requests.AddParameter("{\r\n  \"orderRef\": \"" + LabOrderReference + "\"\r\n}", RestSharp.ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse responses = client.Execute(requests);
```

The link 'http://domain.co.za/services/portal.asmx?op=GetOrderDefinition' contain samples below and i need to pass 'orderRef' when requesting and get back list off order details. Please note that the link has also SOAP 1.1 design for response for now i just included the request part.

```
POST /services/portal.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: test.lensportal.co.za
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.domain.co.za/GetOrderDefinition"


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
 <GetOrderDefinition xmlns="http://www.domain.co.za">
<orderRef>string</orderRef>
</GetOrderDefinition>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: The URL contains a question mark followed by the query parameters : ?op=GetOrderDefinition.  It is a string and you need to include an order number.  You are getting an empty response because the order number is missing.  Parameters are separated using an ampersand.

Comment: I tried to change the GetOrderDefinition with the actual order number parameter (3556) and it gave me an error saying that 'the method 3556 is not found'

Comment: I do not have access to the link that gives sample code.  The order number is a separate parameter from the operation (op) parameter. Something like : ?op=GetOrderDefinition&id=3556

Comment: Can't get to link.